# loading multiple images attachecd to one thumbnail

Tags: c#, gridview, lightbox

Hi coder i search a lot but didn't find what i want

i have a database in which i have path of my images.. now i bind images with by gridview and apply lightbox on it but what i want is to show only one image in front as thumbnail and when i click on that images slide show will start..

this is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="1" PersistedSelection="true" DatakeyNames="pptId">
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField headerText="pptId" DataField="pptId"></asp:BoundField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View PPT">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a id="imageLink" href='<%# Eval("Imageurl") %>' title='<%#Eval("Description") %>'
                        rel="lightbox[Brussels]" runat="server">Show PPT</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
           </asp:GridView>
```

this is my aspx.cs page code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindModule();
}
protected void BindModule()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string id = Request.QueryString["pptId"].ToString();
        //Query to get ImagesName and Description from database
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Image_Master where pptId='" + id + "' and IsEnable='True' order by Priority", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

problem is that when i bind the gridview it will show all images regarding selected pptid and when i click on any images my sildeshow start but what i want is to show only one image and when i click on that image my slide show start. i use lightbox for slide show and my images comes from database

Comment: i didn't find to load multiple images attached to one thumbnail but i got another solution see this link [Hide row of gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379242/how-to-hide-randomly-generated-row-of-gridview)